# Moving object on x axis with mouse move

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, axis

I am trying to create a game where the player drops a cube from the top of the screen to the bottom, collecting points on the way down depending on where they dropped the cube from (like a Coin Pusher arcade game).

At the moment I am able to have my cube move to the mouse, but this in both X and Y values. See -

```
Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
Vector3 mouse = Input.mousePosition;
mouse = mouse;
transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(mouse);
```

I am keen to have movements only on X but am unsure how to achieve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Please read the Tag Guidelines http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging and don't use Tags within Question Titles. Also, unity tag is for Unity IoC Container. Unity3d tag is to be used with Unity3D game engine related questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a few things in your code that are unnecessary, mainly the first and third lines. I will try to simplify your code with my answer.

Anyway, you have the mouse's X and Y, so all you need to do is have your object only move to its X position. Right now you assign the object's entire position to match that of the mouse.

```
Vector3 mouse = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
transform.position = new Vector3(mouse.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
```

This will maintain your object's position along other axes, but align it to the horizontal position of your mouse cursor.

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(mouse).x, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: It's working code. It makes the cube move along X axis according to the movement of mouse. If you look carefully you will see I answered before the accepted answer and they are almost the same. The only difference is that i disabled the move of the cube along the Y axis and Z axis.

Comment: Add this explanation in your answer. :)